# Adding 'Data-Filter' True in code to UL, but doesnt show up on page

Tags: jquery-mobile

So I want to add the data filter to the UL if there are certain number of LI's.  I get the attr to add correctly, but nothing shows up on page.

```
 else
               {
                    $('#presentations').attr("data-filter", "true");
                        $('#presentations').html('');
                              for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                                       $('#presentations').append(
                                       '<li><a href="javascript: loadPresentation(\'' + results.rows.item(i).presentName + '\';");">' + results.rows.item(i).presentName + '</a>'
                                    + '<a href="javascript: deleteConfirm(\'' + results.rows.item(i).presentName + '\');">delete</a></li>');
                                    }
                                   }
                                $('#presentations').listview('refresh');
                                $.mobile.changePage($('#dashboard'), {reloadPage: "true"} );
                                $('#dashboard .message').text('Your presentations');
                            }
```

I'm guessing its a caching issue but I can't figure out how to work around it.  Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried to re-initialize, recreate or refresh the listview but none of it works.

The only way I can get it working is by doing:

```
    $('#listview').listview('option', 'filter', true);
    $('#listview').trigger("listviewcreate");
```

So you trigger manual the `listviewcreate` event and before that you set the filter to true. (setting with `attr(), data() or jqmData()` also doesn't work)

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/N7Z9e/143/

Comment: FREAKING phenomenal!  THANK you so much... nobody has been able to answer this question for me.  I DID have to add one thing to the example, I still had to call refresh before the trigger to get the LI items to get styled by JQmobile.  But this was the answer.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in action - thanks Gerjan!

```
else {
             // don't create duplicate/double filter
             $(".ui-listview-filter").remove();
             if (results.rows.length > 3) { //Add filter search if more than 3 presentations.
                    $('#presentations').listview('option', 'filter', true);
             }
             $('#presentations').html('');
             for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    $('#presentations').append(
                                '<li><a href="javascript: loadPresentation(\'' + results.rows.item(i).presentName + '\');">' + results.rows.item(i).presentName + '</a>'
                             + '<a href="javascript: deleteConfirm(\'' + results.rows.item(i).presentName + '\');">delete</a></li>'
                );
            }
            $('#presentations').listview('refresh');
            $('#presentations').trigger("listviewcreate");
            $.mobile.changePage($('#dashboard'), { reloadPage: "true" });
            $('#dashboard .message').text('Your presentations');
            }
```